# How to send the file is POST request in Ember ? Now only the filename is being sent

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, ember.js, file-upload

```
{{input class="ember-text-field form-control" type="file" value="uploadedFile"}}

<button class="btn btn-success" {{action "triggerUpload"}}>{{"Upload"}}</button>

triggerUpload: function() {
  Ember.$.ajax({
    url: '/api/upload_file', 
    type: 'POST',
    data: this.get('uploadedFile'),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
  });
};
```

This is what I am doing and it sends the file path in the ajax call rather than the file which I want to send to the backend. Am I missing something? Can't I directly send the file through an api ? Want to send a doc file to the backend for processing and saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not send file that simple with ajax requests. You need to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects). This is supported in all modern browsers and IE 10+. If you aiming for older browsers (I hope you not), than you will need to use adobe flash to upload files.

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks.